# ASP.net placing cursor and change focus on enter button

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have a asp website with a page which contains a textbox to enter name,phone number,question and a submit button which submits the details which are entered in the textbox to a server side.

Now when this page is opened there will not be cursor  focus on any textbox. But if i place cursor on name textbox and press enter the focus will goto submit button and it is submit function is called from server side. But i want the cursor to be placed on next textbox when enter button is pressed.And again enter is pressed then cursor should be placed in next textbox and so on. Finally the cursor should come to submit button.

How it can be done?

Comment: You can achieve that with javascript. But i doubt that it's worth the effort since it's not standard and some users might get confused. Enter means submit in web.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating control on enter key is not a best practice in a web application.

It can be accomplished by `javascript` capturing enter key `onkeypress` event

```
function firstElementPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("nextElementId").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

You should use [`tabindex`](http://webcheatsheet.com/HTML/controll_tab_order.php) to provide such a feature in web application.